# Dropdown Menu using javascript, HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to get this to work. I don't wanna put jQuery in yet. Just doing plain javascript. When I click on the image nothing happens. I need it to dropdown the navigation when I click the image. Edited my Javascript code. I added alert to show the current status of what class the toggle is using. But still I cant get to change it from header_navigation_mobile to header_navigation_mobile.is_open

This is my HTML CODE for the Clickable Image

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleMenu()">
    <img class="mobile_navigation_button" src="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/img/menu.svg"/>
</a>
```

This is the HTML for the drop down navigation

```
<div class="header_navigation_mobile">
   <ul>
        <li><a href="{{site.baseurl}}/index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> </a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then my CSS For the Clickable Image to show the navigation

```
.header_navigation_mobile.is_open{
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

This is the CSS for the Clickable Image first state which is to Hide it

```
.header_navigation_mobile{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 290px;
    background: #484547;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Then finally my Javascript

```
function toggleMenu(){
var mobileNav = document.getElementById('mobile_Nav');
var mobileNav_toggle = mobileNav.getAttribute("class");

if(mobileNav_toggle == "header_navigation_mobile") {
    mobileNav_toggle == "header_navigation_mobile.is_open";
}
else {
    mobileNav_toggle == "header_navigation_mobile";
}

alert(mobileNav_toggle);
}
```

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior"*, we don't know what you are wanting to do here. What's going wrong, are there any errors? We can't answer if we don't know what you want.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve]. Specifically: what happens? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

In your JS try like this.use `querySelector` for selecting elements.And for setting and getting css properties use `selector.style.property_name`.

```
function toggleMenu(){
    var mobileNav_Hide = document.querySelector('.header_navigation_mobile');
    var mobileNav_Show = document.querySelector('.header_navigation_mobile.is_open')
    if(mobileNav_Hide.style.display == "none"){
        mobileNav_Show.stylr.display == "block";
    }
    else{
        mobileNav.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would give the menu an ID so it's easier to target, then just toggle a class that you use to hide/show the menu.

```css
.header_navigation_mobile {
  display: none;
}
.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleMenu()">toggle</a>

<div class="header_navigation_mobile" id="mobilenav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{{site.baseurl}}/index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  function toggleMenu(){
    var nav = document.getElementById('mobilenav');
    nav.classList.toggle('open');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a specific answer to your question but may be a handy solution as well. I put together a jsfiddle of a hidden menu you can easily edit to your needs. Here is the link.

```css
#Btn{
 position: fixed;
 right: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 24px;
 background: linear-gradient(#FFF,#DDD);
 border: #AAA 1px solid;
 border-radius: 2px;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: border 0.3s linear 0s;
}
#Btn:hover{
 border: #06F 1px solid;
}
#Btn:hover div{
 background: #06F;
}
#Btn > div{
 width: 20px;
 height: 4px;
 background: #333;
 margin: 3px 0px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 transition: background 0.3s linear 0s;
}
#hidden{
 position: fixed;
 right: -300px;
 top: 60px;
 width: 260px;
 height: 0px;
 background: #333;
 color:#ededed;
 padding:15px;
 transition: right 0.3s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<script>
function toggleBTN(){
 var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden");
 hidden.style.height = window.innerHeight - 60+"px";
 if(hidden.style.right == "0px"){
  hidden.style.right = "-300px";
 } else {
  hidden.style.right = "0px";
 }
}
</script>
<div id="Btn" onclick="toggleBTN()">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div id="hidden">
  <ul>
    <li>MENU ITEM 1</li>
 <li>MENU ITEM 2</li>
 <li>MENU ITEM 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="page_content">
<script>
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ document.write("<h2>"+(i+1)+". Dummy page content ... </h2>"); }
</script>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things in the else statement where is mobileNav coming from there is no instance of that anywhere in your code. Taking a step back a minute from your solution does the adding and removal of the classname is_open define the entire show hide behaviour you desire?

Your process of getting the same element with the subclass present/not present and then trying to set the display property is confusing.

You have an equality comparer when setting the display property when it should be just a single equals which along with my first statement i think is your main problem.

Instead of the way you are doing it i would just look at toggling the is_open class this link [Toggle class on HTML element without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543956/toggle-class-on-html-element-without-jquery) shows how to do that and also demonstrates a few other ways of toggling styles including without javascript

Finally just check because im being lazy that display is valid as a property and that it shouldnt  instead be style.display as others have indicated

Answer (score 0):

```
js
let c = document.getElementById("dropdownlist");
      let e = document.getElementById("dropdownicon");
      let d = e.classList.toggle('fa-angle-down');
      if(d===true) {
        if(c.style.display==='none'){
          c.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
          c.style.display ='block';
        }
      }
      else{
        c.style.display = 'none';
      }
```