# Menu trigger onclick

Tags: javascript, function, drop-down-menu, menu

I want to create a menu for one page site but I'm not very good at JavaScript and I have this code for open and close the menu but I want it to open like with a easy transition because but it just appear.

How can I add fade-in-out or something like that:

```js
 <script>
        function w3_open() {
            document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        function w3_close() {
            document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        </script>
```

```css
w3-button{
  position:fixed; 
     width: 42px;
     height: 42px;
     -moz-border-radius: 50%;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
     line-height:1.1;
     text-align:center;
     top:6.5px; 
     left: 8px; 
     background-color: #f2bd66;
     z-index:11;
     background-position:center;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: white;
     margin-top: 0.7%;
     margin-left: 0.7%;
 }

 .w3-button{
     width: 42px;
     height: 42px;
     margin-top: 0.7%;
     margin-left: 0.7%;
     
 }

 .w3-button::before {
       content:"☰";
       font-size:32px;
       color:white;
       text-align: center;
     }

 .w3-button:hover{
     opacity: 0.6;
     }


  .w3-sidebar {
   position: absolute;
      z-index:12;
      width:188px;
      left: -188px;
      line-height:2;
      position:fixed; 
      border-bottom:.5px solid rgba(204, 158, 90, 1);
      border-top:.5px solid rgba(204, 158, 90, 1);
      background-color:#f2bd66;
      font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;  
   font-weight: 400;
      text-align:center;
      color: #5b5f5e;
      height: 100vh;
      border-right:4px solid #af874b;  
      
    }

    
     
  
  .w3-bar-item {
  width: 188px;
      margin:0 auto;
      line-height:2;
      border-bottom:.5px solid rgba(204, 158, 90, 1);
      border-top:.5px solid rgba(204, 158, 90, 1);
      background-color:transparent;
      font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;  
   font-weight: 400;
      text-align:center;
      color: #5b5f5e;
      float: left;
    }

    #close-menu{
     background-color: #5b5f5e;
     color: white;
    }
    #close-menu:hover{
     opacity: 0.7;
    }




    .nav a:hover {

     background-color: #292446;opacity: 0.9;
     color: white;

    }
```

```html
<div class="w3-sidebar " style="visibility:hidden" id="mySidebar" >
              <button onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-large" id="close-menu"> Close &times;</button>
              <nav class="nav">

                <a href="#inicio" class="w3-bar-item" onclick="w3_close()">Inicio</a>
                <a href="#sobremi" class="w3-bar-item" onclick="w3_close()">Sobre mí</a>
                <a href="#galeria" class="w3-bar-item" onclick="w3_close()">Galería</a>
                <a href="#booktub" class="w3-bar-item" onclick="w3_close()">Booktubers GT</a>
                <a href="#recursos" class="w3-bar-item" onclick="w3_close()">Recursos E-stela</a>
                <a href="#contacto" class="w3-bar-item" onclick="w3_close()">Redes Sociales</a>
              </nav>
          </div>

            <div class="w3-teal">
              <button class="w3-button" onclick="w3_open()"></button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to do that in js, you can make it in pure css :
[Toggle class on HTML element without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543956/toggle-class-on-html-element-without-jquery)

If you still want to use js to achive that, you can toggle a class on your menu container when the button is clicked, and make transition with css based on the toggled class. If you use jquery you can do that with simple jquery fade or slide function :

```
<script>
  $('#my-menu-button').click(function(){
    $('#my-menu').slideToggle();
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a demo for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>demo</title>

    <style>
        .test {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #000;
            display: block; 
            transition: 1s;
            opacity: 0
        }
        .active {
            opacity: 1
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="test"></div>

    <button onclick="show()">show</button>
    <button onclick="hide()">hide</button>

    <script>

        var test = document.querySelector('.test')
        function show () {
            test.className = 'test active'
        }

        function hide () {
            test.className = 'test'
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```